# What does "d'ores et déjà effectués à ce jour" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, droit-et-justice

> Par les présentes, il est rappelé que X deviendra cessionnaire, à
>   titre exclusif, au fur et à mesure de la livraison à X des travaux de
>   programmation et de développement d'ores et déjà effectués à ce jour
>   par le salarié, et ceux qui seront effectués à compter de ce jour,
>   seul ou en collaboration avec les autres salariés, pour le compte et
>   sous la direction de X et dans le cadre de son contrat de travail.

I have trouble understanding what "d'ores et déjà" means here. Does it mean everything "le salarié" has done before now belongs to X?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 « des… et ceux » ? Si vous voulez …

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Leur  formulation n'est pas claire; une formulation qui correspond à la précision demandée dans ce contexte c'est quelque chose comme ce que j'avais écrit en correction, je le crois trop pour changer d'idée.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je ne partage pas ce point de vue non plus ; soit, c'est un langage où les archaïsmes sont plus fréquents (une question de coutume souvent, et un signe de la solidité des principes en matière de législation), mais ma compréhension est que l'on ne représente pas des choses compliquées au moyen d'un langage rudimentaire ; une idée compliquée ne peu être rendue que par une structure linguistique compliquée et la loi et l'administration sont des domaines d'idées compliquées. Ce n'est pas un modèle pour qui n'est pas habitué. Tout d'abord c'est tout un monde de concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Survenant9r7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest, "les travaux (...) d'ores et déjà effectués" refers to the work
done before the contract was signed. However, it doesn't refer to *everything*
the "salarié" has ever done, since this is later qualified by "pour le compte et
sous la direction de X et dans le cadre de son contrat de travail". Thus, only
the work done under X's supervision will belong to X, as is usual.

Comment: Okae thanks for the clarification. In my opinion it seems kind of illogic to add this sentence since no contact has ever been established between the company and the employee.